# No aparece "element style" en mi html y en inspeccionar si

Tags: html, css

Buenas, estoy editando una plantilla que ya viene predefinida pero al intentar modificar el ancho de la imagen que ven en pantalla(donde aparece una persona)no encuentro el elemento de estilo que aparece en la imagen de inspeccionar. En el código html aparece "style" pero luego miro en mi Sublime Text y no aparece nada de eso. ¿Alguien sabe que puede ser? Gracias.
[image: Inspeccionar de Chrome]

[image: Lo que veo en Sublime Text]

Comment: Hola @Natalia, bienvenida a [es.so]! Las imágenes, no sólo hacen imposible copiar tu código para probarlo, sino que también pueden ser difíciles de leer (pensemos en celulares que no definan bien la imagen o en personas con problemas de vista). ¿Podrías por favor incluir el código y el mensaje de error como texto? Encontrarás el enlace para **[edit]** debajo de tu pregunta. Luego de pegarlo, hay que seleccionar el código completamente y hacer click en el botón `{  }`.

Comment: probablemente tu plantilla agrega esos estilos a travez de javascript o jQuery dinamicamente, es por eso que no aparecen dentro del html

Comment: Efectivamente, como no controlo mucho el js, después de mirar por todos lados, encontré que me lo estaba modificando ahí.

Comment: Hola Natalia Camacho en què parte exactamente tienes ese error? yo también lo ando buscando porque quiero editar esa parte pero no aparece en html :(

Answer (score 1):

Eso es porque la plantilla esta usando la librería **[twentytwenty](https://zurb.com/playground/twentytwenty)**, y te agrega esos estilos dinamicamente a través de javascript para lograr ese efecto difuminado que vez a la derecha sobre el texto en la imagen que adjuntas.

Si haces click sobre el "fuego verde" y lo moves hacia izq o derecha con la consola de chrome abierta vas a ver que esos valores se modifican dinamicamente.

Saludos.

Comment: Si, ya descubrí que era por el javascript. Muchas gracias!